# How to handle job recovering in Quartz.Net

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduling, quartz.net, job-scheduling, quartz

I use **Quartz 3.0.7** in my application that use .NET Core 2.2 platform.
I use ms sql server for Quartz action tracking. Quartz tracks and stores its actions in database and it's fine.
Configuration of my StdSchedulerFactory:

```
            ["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "StdScheduler",
            ["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = $"{Environment.MachineName}-{Guid.NewGuid()}",
            ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
            ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true",
            ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
            ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
            // if running MS SQL Server we need this
            ["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz",

            ["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = @"Server=DESKTOP-D64SJFJ\MSSQLSERVER14;Database=quartz;Trusted_Connection=True;",
            ["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer",
            [$"{StdSchedulerFactory.PropertyObjectSerializer}.type"] = "json",
            [StdSchedulerFactory.PropertySchedulerInterruptJobsOnShutdownWithWait] = "true",
```

I want to recover each ***interrupted* Job**. How should I organize logic of my **IHostedService** for supporting **Job Recovering**?
When I Shutdown my application during my job is running then When I start my application again **interrupted job** doesn't run.
My **IHostedService** code:

```
    public class QuartzHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;
    private readonly IJobFactory _jobFactory;
    private readonly IEnumerable<JobSchedule> _jobSchedules;

    public QuartzHostedService(
        ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory,
        IJobFactory jobFactory,
        IEnumerable<JobSchedule> jobSchedules)
    {
        _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
        _jobSchedules = jobSchedules;
        _jobFactory = jobFactory;
    }
    public IScheduler Scheduler { get; set; }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Scheduler = await _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler(cancellationToken);
        Scheduler.JobFactory = _jobFactory;

        await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);

        foreach (var jobSchedule in _jobSchedules)
        {
            var job = CreateJob(jobSchedule);
            var trigger = CreateTrigger(jobSchedule);

            if (!await Scheduler.CheckExists(job.Key, cancellationToken))
            {
                // if the job doesn't already exist, we can create it, along with its trigger. this prevents us
                // from creating multiple instances of the same job when running in a clustered environment
                await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
            }
            else
            {
                // if the job has exactly one trigger, we can just reschedule it, which allows us to update the schedule for
                // that trigger.
                var triggers = await Scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(job.Key);
                if (triggers.Count == 1)
                {
                    await Scheduler.RescheduleJob(triggers.First().Key, trigger);
                }
                else
                {
                    // if for some reason the job has multiple triggers, it's easiest to just delete and re-create the job,
                    // since we want to enforce a one-to-one relationship between jobs and triggers
                    await Scheduler.DeleteJob(job.Key);
                    await Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Scheduler?.Shutdown(cancellationToken);
    }

    private static IJobDetail CreateJob(JobSchedule schedule)
    {
        var jobType = schedule.JobType;
        return JobBuilder
            .Create(jobType)
            .WithIdentity(jobType.FullName)
            .WithDescription(jobType.Name)
            .RequestRecovery(true)
            .StoreDurably()
            .Build();
    }

    private static ITrigger CreateTrigger(JobSchedule schedule)
    {
        return TriggerBuilder
            .Create()
            .WithIdentity($"{schedule.JobType.FullName}.trigger")
            .WithCronSchedule(schedule.CronExpression)
            .WithDescription(schedule.CronExpression)
            .Build();
    }
}
```

My startup.cs:

```
private void ConfigureQuartz(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHostedService<QuartzHostedService>();

        services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, SingletonJobFactory>();
        services.AddSingleton<ISchedulerFactory>(new StdSchedulerFactory(StdSchedulerFactoryConfiguration()));

        services.AddSingleton<AuthKeyExpiresJob>();
        //services.AddSingleton<AuthKeyWillExpireJob>();

        services.AddSingleton(new JobSchedule(
            typeof(AuthKeyExpiresJob),
            "0 14 11 ? * *"));
    }
```